# How do I create new JInternalFrames without overwriting the previous one

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I am creating a simple GUI in Java where I have a button 'Open' which opens a new internal frame where I could draw circle, rectangles etc. I noticed that the newly created frame overwrites the previous since buttons like 'Save' and 'Show graph' (this shows the matrix of the drawn frame) work only for the latest internal frame. I would like to make it possible to work for the selected frame - I could have 2-3 open frames, I select one, and it works for it.

Here's part of my code:

```
public void createFrame() {

    MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(6, 128, 209)));
    MyInternalFrame.net=new PetriNet(this.getWidth()/20,(this.getHeight()-this.toolBarPosition)/20,25,this);
    frame.actionManager=new PetriActionManager(frame.net,frame);

    btnPlace.addActionListener(frame.actionManager); 
    place.addActionListener(frame.actionManager); 

    btnDelPlace.addActionListener(frame.actionManager);
    delPlace.addActionListener(frame.actionManager);

    // Other buttons in the same manner

    imageLabel=new JImageLabel(frame.net.getImage());
    imageLabel.addMouseListener(frame);
    imageLabel.setBounds(0,0,this.getWidth(),
                            this.getHeight()-this.toolBarPosition);
    imageLabel.setVisible(true);
    this.paint(this.getGraphics());

    frame.add(imageLabel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's where I call the function, the button which opens a new internal frame:

```
Action actionNew = new AbstractAction("New Board", iconNew) {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              createFrame(); 
          }
        };
```

'Show graph' button:

```
 if (ev.getActionCommand().equals("Show Graph"))
          {
            MyInternalFrame.net.buildTree();            
            this.graphFrame.setStringTree(MyInternalFrame.net.getStringTree());
            MyInternalFrame.net.buildImage();
            this.paint(this.getGraphics());
            this.graphFrame.setVisible(true);
          }
```

Comment: `buttons like 'Save' and 'Show graph' (this shows the matrix of the drawn frame) work only for the latest internal frame` - well you don't even show the code you use for the "Save" button. I'm guessing you just reference a variable, which of course can only reference one frame at a time which appears to be the last frame you create. The answer given in your previous question is the answer for this question. The code in the ActionListener needs to access the desktop pane and use the appropriate method to get the currently selected internal frame. Read the API.

Comment: @camickr I've added the code for the 'Show graph' button. I've been using Java for a couple of weeks.

Comment: @camickr Any need for 'save' button code :?

Comment: The code you posted is NOT a [mcve]. How does that code compile? When you learn a new concept start with simple code. So I suggest you start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). Download the demo code. The code simply creates an internal frame with a unique title. So modify that code to add a "Save" button to the frame. In the ActionListener for the button you will need to access the desktop pane so you can invoke the method to get the active internal frame.

Comment: Then just display the title of the frame. Once you get this simply concept working, then you use the knowledge to implement the solution for your real application. If you have a problem, then you have a simple `MCVE` to post in the forum. We are not interested in your real application. The point of problem solving is to simplify the problem.

Comment: @camickr MCVE means that the code should be working so everyone could copy and paste it, then run it? When I do this, should I ask a new question?

Comment: The point of creating the MCVE is to simplify the problem. Hopefully you will find the problem and there will be no need to repost the code. But if you follow my suggestion from above and it still doesn't work, then yes post a new question with a proper MVCE showing what you tried.So basically your MCVE will be the code from the tutorial, plus the code to create the "Save" button with an ActionListener. It should probably be less than 10 lines of code to get the button and ActionListener working. Then you can delete this question so it doesn't clutter the forum.

Comment: @camickr May I include my own code instead the one from the tutorial? It would be probably simple, and I'll delete the previous questions.

Comment: NO! Your code is NOT working. Most of your code is completely irrelevant to the stated problem of "determining the active internal frame". That is why you start fresh with the demo code from the tutorial and simply add the button and ActionListener. Forget about your code. Learn the basic concept of getting the active internal frame, by using methods of the JDesktopPane. This is not a complicated task if you actually try it. We are not here to debug you real application!